# The MetadataAddress or Authority must use HTTPS unless disabled for development by setting RequireHttpsMetadata=false

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-appservice

net core application. I have added azure ad authentication. Below is my startup.cs file

```
 services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.Authority = $"{authSettings.Authority}/{authSettings.TenantId}";
                options.Audience = authSettings.ClientId;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidateActor = false,
                };
            });
```

I have deployed application to azure app service. It deployed successfully. I opened swagger and authenticated and tried to hit api. It throws me 500 error. I went to azure app service log stream. It shows me below error message.

```
/appsvctmp/volatile/logs/runtime/0ad1b1161bafbb0b8662db769e40eca0226d3d1d7d4737bdbe13f88e8a4f089b.log
2020-07-18T03:48:32.615339369Z: [INFO]  Hosting environment: Production
2020-07-18T03:48:32.615384568Z: [INFO]  Content root path: /app
2020-07-18T03:48:32.616251458Z: [INFO]  Now listening on: http://[::]:8081
2020-07-18T03:48:32.616952250Z: [INFO]  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
/appsvctmp/volatile/logs/runtime/f342b472edabea44dc320f2bfa84254b92f9d5ddb433c5d248c4cae636eecd28.log
2020-07-18T05:04:03.313150755Z: [INFO]  Hosting environment: Production
2020-07-18T05:04:03.313765848Z: [INFO]  Content root path: /app
2020-07-18T05:04:03.314598838Z: [INFO]  Now listening on: http://[::]:8081
2020-07-18T05:04:03.315059032Z: [INFO]  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---
Starting Live Log Stream ---
2020-07-18T05:12:23  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2020-07-18T05:13:23  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265412299Z: [INFO]  [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265449199Z: [INFO]        An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265456199Z: [INFO]  System.InvalidOperationException: The MetadataAddress or Authority must use HTTPS unless disabled for development by setting RequireHttpsMetadata=false.
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265461099Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerPostConfigureOptions.PostConfigure(String name, JwtBearerOptions options)
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265465899Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265470499Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265475899Z: [INFO]     at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265480298Z: [INFO]  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265484698Z: [INFO]     at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265489098Z: [INFO]     at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265493798Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265498198Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265502598Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265507098Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265511698Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265516198Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265520598Z: [INFO]     at SGRE.SiteEnrichment.WebApi.Startup.<>c.<<Configure>b__5_2>d.MoveNext() in d:\a\1\s\src\app\SGRE.SiteEnrichment.WebApi\Startup.cs:line 211
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265526198Z: [INFO]  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265530698Z: [INFO]     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265535098Z: [INFO]     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265539498Z: [INFO]     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
2020-07-18T05:13:39.265544798Z: [INFO]     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
```

I have set AzureAd:Authority to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ in app service app settings configurations. Can someone help me to understand this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: There are a lot of ready-to-go code samples from MS, I can't believe that their main azure ad authentication integrations have errors. Did you checked https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp?view=aspnetcore-3.1#startup-class or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can get rid of this error by adding **`JwtBearerOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata`** to false as **`ConfigureServices`**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration["Auth0:Authority"];
            options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });          
    }
```

Comment: As per the documentation this property should only be set to false in development environments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions.requirehttpsmetadata?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: For me, I already logged in with different tenant of auth0. so, once I deleted the browser cookies every thing worked fine.

Answer (score 11):

FWIW: I spent an hour not finding the leading space in the url.

`options.Authority = " https://localhost:5005";`
                    `^`

Comment: Did again. 15 minutes until I googled and found my own answer.

Comment: Same scenario in Prod Release today lol, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply choose https endpoints for Audience and Authority.
An example with local ones.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options => {
        options.Audience = "https://localhost:5001/";
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000/";
    });
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was just simply http instead of https in “Authority” attribute of JwtBearer options,

```cs
options.Authority = "https://localhost:5005";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a very niche case, but might help someone...

I got this error when I deployed a very simple demo to an Azure Web App, and didn't delete the existing files.

The existing files included Owin stuff that had been used by the previous app, and this seems to have caused the error.

Deleting the existing files fixed it.