# How do I workaround a false positive: MetadataAddress or Authority must use HTTPS --> RequireHttpsMetadata=false

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web.api (.Net 6) which has been working perfectly. I got a new computer, installed VS, postman, etc. and when I hit my API I get this error (see below).

But when I use my old computer everything works perfectly.

Can anyone think of anything as to why I would experience this behavior?

**Error:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The MetadataAddress or Authority must use HTTPS unless disabled for development by setting RequireHttpsMetadata=false.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerPostConfigureOptions.PostConfigure(String name, JwtBearerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:57877
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjBoWk5vLXZJSkt0WENYeEdWbTk3VmhMcmd0UjFvMzZjZE5ZVk54dk82Z0UifQ.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.mJ4rmtIp3IwqS2e56ON27pDPeBbNW9MYNp7fUpqRtVaSrVa2Ija0mwo8f2XNMaC0FUs2rvjs2wRn7vF1FmhI8-hM9RsC8po1tYkg1QtmOWbpF6SpUZZapyE1QXIRvyfW1InLP7abzCCu0_JHLHx8wXlCYUXYrHtIGBa27fe5jo1LIZXnGl0Ok6aYLBPxsdiryQJaI4VLNp0157PVfr1shayrjjkZ3P67XbbKfMzzspjXNe-ZCbo0lDlwm-PsOEdTlNisRiDpzAYrvdr8yG5IlS9uqVWTHLUH0zhBPQNgYr8relFRiGqjqFt9DKpms9B24P4rI47A6aupgyNYxJFo-g
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 3872
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: d81e91544c174a7c807a7a9f6c5a82d5
Postman-Token: bd3ae0bd-8d5b-44f4-bc49-296140d09300
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62964949/the-metadataaddress-or-authority-must-use-https-unless-disabled-for-development).